# How does MySQL deal with multiple inserts at the same time with unique values?

Tags: mysql, multithreading

Suppose I have a website which allows users to create an account.  I have user A and user B trying to register for my website.  User A and User B both has chosen the same user name and the user name field in the Database table is unique.  Both hit Register at the same exact time and the network conditions are the same let's assume some how the query reaches the database at the same time.  How does MySQL deal with this? What happens?

If my question is too big to answer here please refer me to some source with the info so that I may study it.